# how to replace the last octet of an IP address in pandas

Tags: regex, pandas, ip

I have this simple dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'myip' : ['192.168.0.1']})

df
Out[12]: 
          myip
0  192.168.0.1
```

I want to use `str.replace` to replace the last octet of the ip with `0` (so that it would appear as `192.168.0.0`

I (think I) know how to match the last octet in regex: `\\.[0-9]*$`, but I dont get the `pandas` syntax to replace it by zero.

Any ideas? Pandas 23 here. Thanks!

Comment: `df['myip'] = df['myip'].str.replace(r'\.\d+$', '.0')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
>>> df['myip'] = df['myip'].str.replace(r'\.\d+$', '.0')
>>> df
          myip
0  192.168.0.0
>>>
```

Here, `\.` matches a dot, `\d+` matches 1 or more digits, and the `$` anchor asserts the position at the end of the string.

The `.0` is simple string replacement pattern, a dot followed with a `0` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MGA5Es/1).

Comment: haha nice trick! I am using python3 and I am always confused as to use raw strings or not. does that matter here?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ In this case, you may omit `r` prefix, but I'd rather use it always unless there is a very specific case.

Comment: ok thanks. that essentially avoids the need for double backslashing if I understand well

Comment: Yes, `'\\\\[^/]+'` = `r'\\[^/]+'`

Comment: thanks. that might be a side note, but i dont get why you can use just one ` \ ` for `\. ` while you need to use two `\\ `  in ` \ \ [ ` In both cases we use the raw strings... –

Comment: sorry for the poor formatting, it does not seem to play well with all these characters

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Make sure you match what you need. ``r'\\['`` is not the same as ``r'\['``